# Mobile Safari is displaying the wrong image

Tags: jquery, ios, image, mobile, safari

On my site ([destinyexotics.com](http://www.destinyexotics.com)), I am using jQuery and JS to generate divs containing images and stats about items. When hovering over the item, the data can be viewed.

The problem is that Safari on iOS 8 (only seen here so far) is showing the wrong images, even though the HTML is correct. As verified on the safari dev console, my HTML is exactly as it should be, however the actual image itself is displaying another (seemingly random) image.

Here is a screenshot of it happening: http://www.imgur.com/VsYvwTL,SCN1wRf and if you view the website on a computer, you should see that the Exotics categories will be yellow, everything else will be purple.

I can't figure out why the browser is displaying the wrong images and unfortunately at least one of my users is having the same issue. I have only seen it once, and I killed safari and reloaded to fix the problem, but apparently this is not working for my user.

Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Got the same issue today, no idea what's causing it though, we're desperately trying to find a fix... :(

Comment: Best I've been able to figure out, it's a bug with mobile safari. It happens infrequently, but plenty enough to be a problem, and there's absolutely nothing that I've found that will help.

With that said, clearing the cache does seem to fix the problem every time.

Comment: @itsOgden It's the same problem mentioned on https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6574663 . Have you managed to find anything that fixes it?